# Brute Forcing Application with itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools, brute-force

I am trying to write an application to brute force a fully lower case, letters only, 6 character long password that has 2 letters repeating twice. I tried using `itertools.product(string.lowercase, 6)` but even though I have a very "beefy" computer, it didnt have enough RAM to finish up computing, that is because `itertools` actually builds a whole list before returning it.

So then I thought of having a list like so `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and it would count from right to left, everytime an index hits 26 it would go back to 0 and the slot to it's left would increment 1, except I havent figured out a way to code that.

I've been trying to crack a work arround on this one for quite a while now and turning here is my last resort, any algorithm tips are very welcome. I'm sorry to make this sort of a "homework" type question, but I am really dumbfounded by this one.

Comment: "that is because itertools actually builds a whole list before returning it."  No.  `itertools.product` doesn't materialize the list.

Comment: Why do not use 6 nested "for" loops on a-z lists and a concatenation in the innermost loop?

Comment: @LuizBerti, `itertools.product` returns an iterator, not a list. Try `for x in itertools.product(string.lowercase, repeat=6): print(x)`

Comment: @LuizBerti: not much to add beyond falsetru's example.  I'll note though that if you know that you have 2 letters repeating twice, you can use other itertools functions to dramatically speed up the search process by starting only from feasible letter collections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using something like this will work without taking much memory:

```
import itertools
import string

for guess in itertools.product(string.lowercase, repeat=6):
    if checkguess(''.join(guess)):
        print("Password is: {0}".format(''.join(guess)))
```

`itertools.product` generates the possible combinations one by one. It does not return anything, it is a generator function. See the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). All the functions in `itertools` behave like or handle iterators, hence the name.

If your code takes up much memory, you might want to post it here, so we may find the culprit.

Based on DSM's suggestion for faster code, you can do something like this:

```
import string
from itertools import product, combinations, permutations

for guess_chars in combinations(string.lowercase, 4):
    for doubled_chars in combinations(guess_chars, 2):
        for guess in permutations(guess_chars + doubled_chars):
            #...
```